# Form submit behavior with nested forms in angularJs

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, forms

```
<form name="v" ng-submit="submit()" ng-controller="ExampleController">
  Enter text and hit enter OUTER FORM:
  <input type="text" ng-model="text" name="texta" />
  <input type="submit" id="submit" value="Submit" />
  <pre>list={{list}}</pre>

  <form name="x" ng-submit="submitInner()">
    Enter text and hit enter INNER FORM:
    <input type="text" ng-model="textInner" name="text" />
    <input type="submit" id="submits" value="Submit" />
    <pre>lists={{listInner}}</pre>        
  </form>
</form>
```

example  : [Plnkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/90MO0PQUqqVE212lNyMe?p=preview)

I have an angular `form` inside a `form`. When I select inner field and hit enter, the outer form submit action is called.
I am expecting it to call the inner form submit action
**Am I expecting wrong, if yes why? and how to achieve the intended behavior**

Below is from angular doc(https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/form):

> - If a form has only one input field then hitting enter in this field triggers form submit (ngSubmit)
> - if a form has 2+ input fields and no buttons or input[type=submit] then hitting enter doesn't trigger submit
> - if a form has one or more input fields and one or more buttons or input[type=submit] then hitting enter in any of the input fields will
>     trigger the click handler on the first button or input[type=submit]
>     (ngClick) and a submit handler on the enclosing form (ngSubmit)

Comment: @mplungjan angularJs allow nested forms

Comment: I would still avoid the name/id/functionname="submit"

Answer (score 3):

Nested `form`s are not allowed per HTML standards, but you could make it working using `ng-form` directive instead of `form` element.

For having nested form you need to replace all the inner form's with `ng-form` and those form which are trans-piled to `ng-form` would no longer support `ng-submit` event. You should add those form method on `ng-click` of button & also change input type from `type="submit"` to `type=button""`.

**Markup**

```
<form name="v" ng-submit="submit()" ng-controller="ExampleController">
  Enter text and hit enter OUTER FORM:
  <input type="text" ng-model="text" name="texta" />
  <input type="submit" id="submit" value="Submit" />
  <pre>list={{list}}</pre>

  <ng-form name="x">
    Enter text and hit enter INNER FORM:
    <input type="text" ng-model="textInner" name="text" />
    <input type="button" id="submits" value="Submit" ng-click="submitInner()"/>
    <pre>lists={{listInner}}</pre>
  </ng-form>

</form>
```

[**Plunkr Here**](http://plnkr.co/edit/WSoLpjJuamRcHMpFEdoC?p=preview)

Comment: still doesnt work and plunkr shared by you also doesnt work in term of "type in something in inner input field and hit enter... it still submit the outer form"

Comment: @user2410148 you could get outer form working on enter click, because it has `ng-submit` event..inner form as not using `ng-submit` so they will not work as they had `type="button"`

Comment: @user2410148 ng-submit event will only available if you are using `form` element itself.

Comment: @Pankaj, If add required validation on outer form or inner form it's not effecting. How do we check $error on inner and  outer form separately. Plunker: http://plnkr.co/edit/K5fbm3gAFcRDYvGI7EYw?p=preview